# Mean or Sum of objective function matters in optimization?

Tags: optimization, rcpp, numerical-methods, nonlinear-optimization

I'm using `RcppEnsmallen` to estimate quantile regression models. I think I have set up everything right, but problems have been constantly emerging. I've tried two strategies:

Strategy 1: in the objective function, return `sum` of all errors. The corresponding `gradient` setup is similar. I tried `0.1` quantile in my example. However, occasionally I can get correct answers. Most of the time, it returns `NaN`.

Strategy 2: The objective function changed to `mean` of the sum of all errors. The `gradient` setup is also use the `mean` version. However, in this scenario, it returns quite different values each time, far from the correct answers.

I was wondering where the problem might be? Thanks.

```
#include <RcppEnsmallen.h>
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppEnsmallen)]]


class QuantileRegressionFunction
{
public:
  // Construct the QuantileRegressFunction with the given data.
  QuantileRegressionFunction(const arma::mat& X,
                             const arma::colvec& y
                  ) : X(X),y(y){}
  
  // Define the objective function.
  double Evaluate(const arma::mat& beta){
     // arma::vec residual1 = y - X * beta;
   return  arma::sum( (y - X * beta) % (  0.1 - arma::ones(y.n_rows) % (  (y - X * beta) <0  )) );
    }
  
  void Gradient(const arma::mat& beta, arma::mat& gradient)
    
  { 
    gradient = -X.t() * ( 0.1 - arma::ones(y.n_rows) % ( (y - X * beta) <0 ) ) ; 
    
    }
  
private:
   const arma::mat& X;
   const arma::vec& y;
  };

// [[Rcpp::export]]

arma::mat qr_reg(const arma::mat&X, const arma::vec&y){
  QuantileRegressionFunction qrf(X,y);
 
  ens::L_BFGS lbfgs;
  lbfgs.MaxIterations()= 100000 ;
  lbfgs.MaxLineSearchTrials() = 10000;
  //lbfgs.ArmijoConstant() = 1e-10;
  arma::mat beta(X.n_cols, 1 , arma::fill::randn);
  
  lbfgs.Optimize(qrf,beta);
  return beta;
  }
```